# Configuring NTP server on a virtual machine and have it point to the physical machine

Tags: redhat, virtual-machines, ntp

I have a virtual machine running on a physical machine, both using RHEL 7/CentOS 7. I need to configure the virtual machine to serve as an NTP Server and have this NTP server point to the physical machine.

Both the machines have chronyd installed by default and both are enabled. Do I append the IP address of the physical machine to the /etc/chrony.conf file on the virtual machine in the pool section? Or vice versa?

I had tried removing the default pool servers from the virtual machine and added in only the IP address of the physical machine. I then ran a chronyc soures -v but shows the IP address of the physical machine to be unreachable.

Comment: It sounds like you have some networking configurations to review but what really tickles me is why the heck do you want to set up a VM that does what the host already does?

Comment: This is a practice question for the rhcsa and the book does a horrible job of explaining how to do it. It just says edit the /etc/chrony.conf in the server section to have the IP address of the physical machine.